# How to get username back on the Unity panel?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, kdm

Installed kdm and used it as default. 
After i login into unity through i do not see my username.But if i go back to using lightdm, i have no problems.

Anyone knows how to use kdm as default and still not lose username in unity..?

Comment: Was it present when you first installed / updated to Ubuntu **12.04** ?

Comment: yes it was present..

Comment: Mine disappeared on **11.10** (after some update), but is present on new install of **12.04 LTS** (so far) ..

Answer (score 3):

To re-enable the username on Unity panel, in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

To disable, simply change `true` to `false`:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

**Note:** You must reboot for these changes to take effect.

Comment: I did say it in the question this is not working

Comment: @tanmay.01 If you were referring to the GUI for dconf, there _shouldn't_ be an option for session under com > canonical > indicator, although I do not know why. But the `show-real-name-on-panel` boolean key should definitely work in defining the state of your username in the panel. Please give the commands a try in your terminal, and be sure to reboot. Get back to me! :)

Comment: Nope .. its not working.. in last 1 year this is the first time unity is troubling me..

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once-- Try this command in Terminal:

`sudo apt-get install indicator-session`

What may have happened is that the package was deleted. Like I said, it happened once to me, so thiS MAY (I can't stress that word enough) work for you. :)

Comment: yes tried this also ...but in wain